# Is there any reason not to include issue numbers in debug logs?

Tags: security, coding-standards, logging

I was going through the answers to this question:

[What information must never appear in logs?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/54008/what-information-must-never-appear-in-logs)

And noticed that nobody mentioned this particular attribute. It's something I find useful- whenever any logging is added to the system as a result of tracing a particular issue raised in the bug tracker, or adding a feature, ***I tend to include the ticket number of the related helpdesk element.***

This means that when going through the log, any programmer can cross reference each log message with the associated ticket number. Now I understand that using proper VCS/helpdesk integration means most commits are attached to a ticket number anyway- but over time it makes it easy for us to diagnose problems on inspection whenever a log message comes up.

However it still makes me a bit uneasy leaving this in the logs. The problem is, I can't think of a scenario where this could become a problem. I'm hoping SE can help me out.

By the way- I'm talking about the "verbose" log level. This is never done in a logging level that will appear in production.

Answer (score 5):

> I can't think of a scenario where this could become a problem

In my past projects, I've been through 3 or 4 bug tracker migrations that changed (invalidated) all the bug IDs used in prior tracker.

Within bugtrackers themselves, that wasn't a problem since back-references to older issues at prior tracker were easy to discover. But I can easily imagine it making a major headache when posted in a plain text application log, especially when there will be mixes of "old" and "new" tracker IDs.

- `known issue, details in PRJ-12345`
  refers to old tracker used *before* Jun 2012
- `known issue, details in PRJ-23451`
  refers to new tracker used *after* to 2012

It would be quite difficult to figure which of (two) trackers above messages refer to.

I find that it's better to just make sure that log messages are unique, ie **guarantee that developer will be able to track the message back to *single* point in source code** (more on that below).

At that *single point* referred from logs, one can use comments to point reader to exact URL of the respective issue when needed.

```
    // known issue, details in http://oldtracker/PRJ-12345
    // known issue, details in http://newtracker/PRJ-23451
```

---

Side note, a "nice" example of what is bad about not having unique log messages is a Tomcat bug [27988  Unhelpful FileNotFoundException](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=27988). Its description sounds like a royal road to maintenance nightmare...

> `org.apache.naming.resources.DirContextURLConnection` raises FileNotFoundException
>   on lines **311, 344, 382 and 396**.  It would be more helpful if these provided a
>   message string

...and in my experience, it really was a nightmare.

Guess what happens when your application crashes with braindead `file not found` and there are (at least) four reasons for that and log doesn't give you a slightest idea what could really go wrong there.

Amount of curses I sent over to Apache developers is hard to count.